# Best bits to use for cutting/drilling glass?

Tags: glass

What are the best bits to use for drilling and cutting glass, mainly bottles? Tools using would be cordless drill/driver and dremel.

Comment: Glass cutters and a flat blade screwdriver works for making holes. Glass does not like high speeds…

Comment: Tools for cutting glass are different than tools for drilling glass. Also, "best" is looking for opinion, which is off topic here. If you'll describe what you're trying to accomplish, people may come up with suggestions for you.

Comment: If by cutting you mean in a straight round line, cut a bottle in half, then there are bottle cutters that do a better job than by handheld power tools(dremels).

Comment: A quality glass cutter is what is used for cutting glass making a jig to assure a straight cut helps. A single score line all the way around the bottle then tap and snap, I had a friend that owned a flower shop and I made a vase out of a fancy beer bottle the brand was in the glass. She filled it with flowers for another friend and asked me to show her how I did it, she was making them for her shop and they were selling like hotcakes. She started doing square bottles and made a better jig than the crude one I made that stuck in the opening, hers had wheels she could adjust in and out for size.

Comment: Just checked on amazon, since I had a bottle cutting kit when young, yes they are that old.  Found there is such a thing as special bottle cutting oil and it is expensive as it sounds.

Comment: i use a cheap hollow drill bit from ebay/china to make my bottle lamps. they look like tiny hole saws with grit around the rim like a margarita glass. They work well. Drill under running water using oven gloves to protect your hands. Sometimes it helps to abrade a small slot with the corner of the bit to get it started. Be gentle and let the drill speed and grit do the work for you. You can hot glue a washer or nut onto the bottle as a template if you have unsteady hands.

Comment: `best` is a meaningless term ... a person's definition of best, is not necessarily your definition